# How to reliably determine the calling assembly in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, reflection, clr

In .NET 3.5 and lower, the following (slightly crude example) works pretty well:

Assembly A:

```
public static class ClassInAssemblyA
{
    public static string GetCallingAssemblyLocation()
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName(false).CodeBase;
    }
}
```

Assembly B:

```
public class ClassInAssemblyB
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; private set; }

    public ClassInAssemblyB()
    {
        AssemblyName = ClassInAssemblyA.GetCallingAssemblyLocation();
    }
}
```

Assembly C:

```
var assemblyName = new ClassInAssemblyB().AssemblyName;
Assert.That(assemblyName.Contains("AssemblyB"));
```

Unfortunately the .NET 4.0 CLR seems to be optimized to inline the AssemblyA code into AssemblyB, and so the above test actually passes when executed in Debug mode, but *fails in release mode*. It's basically impossible to reproduce the error while stepping through.

One way to stop the inlining is to require the **caller** to add the attribute `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` every time they reference AssemblyA. This is a kludgy solution that requires the caller to know the inner workings of the library, and it shouldn't be their problem, so I am not willing to go this route.

**Are there any alternative ways to figure out at runtime what the filename is of the calling assembly**?

Comment: Why do you need to know the calling assembly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any solution other than using `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining`.  See the documentation for [GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx), which includes almost this exact scenario.  Also, note that you need to add the attribute to **both** the method in A and the method in B, since inlining either into its calling assembly would result in the behavior that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that JIT compiler will always respect `[Flags(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` except *possibly* in the case that you are trying to test a self-recursive call.

This is based on

1. the documentation of MethodImplOptions (which seems to call out tail recursion as a special case)
2. a quotation of the CLI spec discussed here:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/509557-race-conditions-c-eventing

(which didn't discuss tail recursion as far as I read)